# Mocking getProperties() of WCMUsePojo in Junit and Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, aem

I am writing Junit test cases for my classes extending WCMUsePojo but I am not able to mock the value of getProperties() method which returns a Value Map. As a result I get null pointer exception whenever we fetch any key from the Value map. Can anybody help.

Comment: Can you post your code? Both the `WCMUsePojo` class and the test. It's difficult to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Apart from the code, testing WCMUsePojo is quite difficult, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644055/unit-test-wcmusepojo-class

Answer (score 0):

Create a ValueMap with mock values. When you are mocking getProperties() method then return your mock ValueMap.

```
ValueMap mockValueMap = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap());
mockValueMap.put("test", "value");
```